# I can break you. What am I?

Tags: rhyme

> I can break you,
>
> Or take you,
>
> And captivate you forever.
>
> I strike you,
>
> In moments where you’re weak.
>
> I strike you so that
>
> Forget me you will never.
>
> This arrow pierces you deep and sound.
>
> Come get me before your life runs aground.

---

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it may be ...

> love

... because ...

> Love can break you (or your heart) of course,
>  it can take you (which has many different meanings here ...),
>  and ideally, it continues forever (*captivate you*).
>
>  It may strike you, in case your hopes/wishes are not fulfilled or you're frustrated.
>  This may be the case especially if you're weak (if you're not in a good situation because love always consumes resources, most notably time).
>
>  *I strike you so that you will never forget me* could also mean, that you never forget **the one** who broke your heart.
>
>  The *arrow* may be a metaphor for Amor's arrow. When he shot it, the target falls in love immediately. The arrow actually hits you *deep* in your body -- directly in your heart.
>  If that cracks, it makes a *sound*. Alternatively, you make the sound by crying about the love you may lost or may get. Whatever.
>
>  *Come get me before your life runs aground* is a little bit weird for me. But it may mean that you should try to get someone to love before you die (*run aground* ?).

Comment: The "sound" thing is sort of like "safe and sound" not "he made a sound." :)